# I need to get info on one line cleaned up in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

OK, I have been able to web scrape the info i need from a website, clean it up and format it the way I want.  The problem is I need the description and price on one line.  I have been able to do it but with indented spaces.  I can't figure out how to clean it up all on one line.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

b = open ('canadianappliances.csv', 'a', newline='')
a = csv.writer(b, delimiter=',')


r = requests.get("http://www.canadianappliance.ca/Refrigerators-And-Fridges-3/Full-Size-Refrigerators-38/French-Door-Refrigerators-48/?per_page=all")

r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")


g_data = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "product_link"})
p_data = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "pi-price-final"})

for item in g_data:
    print(item.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "))

for price in p_data:
    print(price.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "))

for g, p in zip(g_data, p_data):
    print(g.text, p.text)
```

Comment: You could zip them together into a tuple and then iterate on the tuple.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Sorry, just added the zip.  I need the zip to be on one line.  I am using Python 3.5

Comment: Use `print(g.text.strip().replace('\n',' '), p.text.strip())`. The values have a lot of whitespace. You need to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text values of the scraped `g_data` and `p_data` have a lot of whitespace on the sides. You need to remove them to print each item in one line. Like:

```
>>> for g,p in zip(g_data, p_data):
...     print g.text.strip().replace('\n',' '), p.text.strip()
...
Samsung - RF220NCTASR $1,397.72
Samsung - RF18HFENBSR $1,599.00
Samsung - RF23HCEDBSR $2,179.92
Samsung - RF28HMEDBSR $2,498.78
# and it goes on and on and on
```

I'm using Python 2.7 if you are wondering where the parentheses of the `print` statement went.